# Change a dataframe column value based on the current value?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns and in one of them, there are string values. I need to change these strings to an acceptable value based on the current value. The dataframe is relatively large (40.000 x 32)

I've made a small function that takes the string to be changed as a parameter and then lookup what this should be changed to.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['Script','Scrpt','MyScript','Sunday','Monday','qwerty'],
    'B': ['Song','Blues','Rock','Classic','Whatever','Something']})

def lut(txt):
    my_lut = {'Script' : ['Script','Scrpt','MyScript'],
            'Weekday' : ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday']}

    for key, value in my_lut.items():
        if txt in value:
            return(key)
            break
    return('Unknown')
```

The desired output should be:

```
    A       B
0   Script      Song
1   Script      Blues
2   Script      Rock
3   Weekday     Classic
4   Weekday     Whatever
5       Unknown     Something
```

I can't figure out how to apply this to the dataframe.
I've struggled over this for some time now so any input will be appreciated

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['Script','Scrpt','MyScript','Sunday','sdfsd','qwerty'],
    'B': ['Song','Blues','Rock','Classic','Whatever','Something']})

dic = {'Weekday': ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'], 'Script': ['Script','Scrpt','MyScript']}

for k, v in dic.items():
  for item in v:
    df.loc[df.A == item, 'A'] = k

df.loc[~df.A.isin(k for k, v in dic.items()), 'A'] = "Unknown"
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I changed your data frame slightly so I could test out the code. It works for the example df you gave in your question as well.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was focused on not "loop" thru the df more than needed. I didn't try the   "other direction" (maybe that's not case "behind the scenes" here).

Comment: @HoBe Glad it worked! If it's possible, could you please mark this answer as the solution so it can help others looking into a similar issue? Thanks!